# Web.config : Allow Users in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

My requirement is to deny access to all users except for few for a specific file  , So I have specified the path : `_vti_bin/_vti_adm/admin.dll`  and mentioned the allow users and deny users  as below .
I am able to restrict the path but not able to login using  “domain\Username” even though it was specified in allow users.

Please let me know what is missing !!

```
<location path="_vti_bin/_vti_adm/admin.dll" >
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users ="domain\Username"/>
<deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Just thinking...same question at same time on 2 different forum by different users.   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfadcc78-af4b-4a28-8171-dc1e4557fc04/webconfig-allow-users-in-sharepoint-2007?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: We are in same team, same company,same collaboration group :)

Comment: Great...i was looking for ur problem and got it on MSDN.